# linq for 2 dimensional array with all

Tags: c#, linq

```
[0,0,0]
[1,1,1]
[2,2,2]
```

I have the above 2 dimensional array.

I need to check for 3 things, first is to check if all the cells are filled just like above.

Second:

```
[0,0,0]
[1]
[]
```

For the above array, I need to check if all the cells are populated per row.

Third:

```
[0,]
[1,1]
[2,2,2]
```

I want to find if the first elements of first column are populated.

I can do it with foreach loops, or for loop. but i want to use `All(predicate)` with linq.

```
            foreach (var ticketValue in ticketValues)
            {
                firstRow = ticketValue.All(x => x == i);

                foreach (var value in ticketValue)
                {

                }
            }
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly want to do.  Could you either list the expected outputs or write the `foreach` version of what you want to do?

Comment: Do you mean to say 3 dimensional array?

Comment: Might be good to give some code examples, because your description is very vague.  I gather that the first array is some sample data [not array declaration] but the second example is FUBAR?  How can a row element *NOT* be populated from the description given [int, 2d array] it *MUST* be populated.

Comment: @chridam It's 2-dimensional. It only has 2 axes.

Comment: @NPSF3000 It looks like a jagged array, not a rectangular one.

Comment: @ananthonline if it's a jagged array then the OP has given us very incorrect description - which is why I want code samples before wasting time solving it.

Comment: it s not a jagged array, it s 2 dimensional int [][] .

Comment: `int [][]` has 2 dimensions, but it is also a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx).  Can you at the very least let us know the result type for each check?  Do they all return `bool`, or does the second one return a list of `bool`s?

Comment: @DarthVader This 'int[,]' is a two dimensional array.  This 'int[][]' is a jagged array.  They are very different structures.

Comment: does it make a difference? al i want to know is that 3 cases. you can even call it matrix or whatever, I do initialize it as a rectangular array. u call it jagged array. please look at what i want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're setting up that 2D like this:

```
int?[][] myArrayA = new int?[][] { new int?[] {0,0,0}, new int?[] {1,1,1}, new int?[] {2,2,2} };
int?[][] myArrayB = new int?[][] { new int?[] {0,0,0}, new int?[] {1}, new int?[] {null} };
int?[][] myArrayC = new int?[][] { new int?[] {0,null}, new int?[] {1,1,1}, new int?[] {2,2,2} };
```

So, using Linq we do this:

```
bool FirstCheck(int?[][] theArray)
{
    int size = (from arrays in theArray select arrays.GetUpperBound(0)).Max();

    var check = from arrays in theArray
                where theArray.All(sub => sub.GetUpperBound(0) == size)
                select arrays;

    return size + 1 == check.Count<int?[]>();
}

bool SecondCheck(int?[][] theArray)
{
    int size = (from arrays in theArray select arrays.GetUpperBound(0)).Max();

    var check = from arrays in
                    (from subs in theArray
                     where theArray.All(sub => sub.All(value => value != null))
                     select subs)
                where arrays.GetUpperBound(0) == size
                select arrays;

    return size + 1 == check.Count<int?[]>();
}

bool ThirdCheck(int?[][] theArray)
{
   int size = (from arrays in theArray select arrays.GetUpperBound(0)).Max();

   var check = from arrays in theArray
               where theArray.All(array => array[0].HasValue)
               select arrays;

   return size + 1 == check.Count<int?[]>();
}
```

Hope that's what you were wanting...